# How to add App to “Open In” menu iOS for own app?

Tags: ios

I have provided document types in my Info.plist, other apps that recognize that   document type list my app in their "open in" choices. But my app does not list in my "Opne in " choices. How to do that ?

Comment: Why would you want the current app to appear in the "Open In" menu that it is presenting? Why would a user choose to export data from the current app only to import it into the current app?

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to list other apps that can open a document type in his app's "Open in" menu, but the question is confusing. OP, can you clarify?

Comment: I have a post section  and chat section in my app . I preview the posted pic in UIDocumentInteractionController.So if user want to send any posted pic to chat anyone he can go to post section , preview it and than should be able to send anyone via chat section.